# Testing with Jest. Test fails when it should throw

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

So I have this class with select method that takes ID and returns a Promise. I want to test it with Jest and I am expecting the test to fail if there is no parameter passed into select().

Hopefully some of you can direct me onto good path so I can solve that problem.

Expected behaviour: test Throws if ID is not passed

Actual behaviour: test fails with following result

terminal

```
Running tests for class DB › SELECT() method tests will follow › Throws if ID is not passed

expect(received).resolves.toEqual()

Received promise rejected instead of resolved
Rejected to value: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined]

  35 |     it("Should resolve if data.id is not passed", () => {
  36 |       const newDB = new DB();
> 37 |       expect(newDB.insert()).resolves.toEqual({});
     |       ^
  38 |     });    

  at expect (node_modules/expect/build/index.js:134:15)
  at Object.<anonymous> (05/DB.test.js:37:7)
```

database.js

```
export default class DB {
constructor() {
    this._rows = [];
}
select(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.async(() => {
            const [row = null] = this._rows.filter(item => item.id === id);
            if(row) {
                resolve(row);
            } else {
                reject('ID not found');
            }
        });
    });
}

async(callback, ...params) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        callback(...params);
    }, Math.random() * 100);
}}
```

database.test.js

```
it("Throws if ID is not passed", async () => {

  const dataBase = new DB();
  expect.assertions(1);
  // return dataBase.select().catch(e => expect(e).toThrow()); <--- doesn't work either
  await expect(dataBase.select()).rejects.toThrow('error');
});
```

Comment: oh sorry. I just accidentally copied wrong lines.I have fixed that now.

Comment: I have updated the log from terminal so it should be accurate now.

Comment: The error says that the problem is in another test, `Should resolve if data.id is not passed`. It likely was logged during `Throws if ID is not passed` because there is no await in highlighted code. It should have been `await expect(newDB.insert()).resolves.toEqual({})`. And then it's that test that needs to be investigated. `insert` wasn't shown. In case the problem persists, please, isolate the problem and provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for it.

Answer (score 0):

Import the DB, spy on the select method, and mock its implementation.

```
js
const dataBase = new DB();

jest.spyOn(dataBase, 'select').mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject());

await expect(dataBase.select()).rejects.toThrow('error')
```